# How to skip saving and updating processes if an object (stored in the database) is 'public'?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, class, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I am using Ruby on Rails 3.1 and I would like to "protect" "particular" objects (stored in the database) from being updated. That is, a my class has an attribute used to store if an object is `public` or `private` and I would like to make possible to update that object only if it is `private`, otherwise do nothing (that is, do not update the object, *silently*).

In other words, *I would like to skip saving and updating processes if the object is `public`.* No more.

**How should I proceed to accomplish to that?**

*P.S.*: Maybe I can use "conditional"/"dynamic" `attr_accessible` attributes, but I am not sure if that approach follows the "Ruby on Rails Way". Furthermore, I don't know if it is possible to make that by using Ruby on Rails.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like a perfect case for a validation.

```
validate :is_not_protected

def is_not_protected
  self.errors.add(:base, 'This object is protected and cannot be changed.') if self.protected?
end
```

Comment: I would like to make that *silently* (that is, without to generate validation errors). Simply, I would like to do *not* change some attribute values on saving and updating if the object is `public`.

Comment: You don't have to show generated validation errors; in your controller, if the update fails, just don't add the errors to the flash and don't rerender the form. If you really don't want any errors to be added, have the validation method just return false. It will cancel the save and no errors will be added to the object, but there will probably come a time when the lack of messaging around this will confuse you or a user.

Comment: I don't need that validation and to generate errors. In other words, *I would like to skip saving and updating processes if the object is `public`*. No more.

Comment: Read my comment again... I said in there what to do if you want to skip saving. Just have the validation return false if the object is public; no errors will be added to the object and the save or update will be cancelled.

Comment: *BTW*: In my case the validation "breaks" my other implemented processes on displaying errors in the front-end content.